# Names of God in Eicha

Tags: tanach, lamentations-eicha

The name אדני is used with unusual frequency in Eicha, but not exclusively. Why does the the book change back and forth? (I mention the frequency to explain why my question about the switching is specifically about Eicha)

The only one I have seen who notes this is Yaakov Klein in the Mikra L'Yisrael Series, (p55-56):

> תופעה אחרת ראויה לציון, הקשורה למסירת הטקסט של המגילה, היא ריבוי הכתיבה של שם ה' בצורה 'אֲדֹנָי' בנציגים העיקריים של נוסח המסורה ( כתב יד לנינגרד וכתר ארם- צובה ) , במקום השם המפורש המרובע ( יהוה ) . בעוד שהשם המרובע מופיע בכתבי יד אלה 32 פעמים ( א, ה, ט, יא-יב, יז-יח, כ ; ב, ו, ז ג , ח-ט, יז, כ א , כב ; ג, יח, כב, כד-כו, מ, נ, נה, סא, סד, סו ; ד, יא, טז, כ ; ה, א, יט, כא ) , הצורה 'אֲדנָי' ( שהיא גם הקריאה התמידית של השם המפורש בנוסח המסורה ) מופיעה 14 פעם ( א, יד-טו ; ב, א-ב, ה, ז א , יח-יט, כ ב ; ג, לא, לו-לז, נח ) , משמע היחס בין הצורות הוא בקירוב 2 : 1 . יש להדגיש, כי בכל המקרים האלה מדובר בהיקרות הצורה 'אדנָי' בנפרד, כשמדובר על ה' בגוף שלישי, להוציא מקרה אחד של פנייה ישירה לה' ( ג, נח ) , שבו הצורה יכלה להתפרש כתואר של כבוד במשמע 'אדונִי' ( היינו 'אדון' עם כינוי הקניין למדַבר ) . אולם, בדיקת כתבי יד רבים של נוסח המסורה של המגילה הראתה, כי בתשעה-עשר מהמקרים השם המרובע לא מיוצג בצורה 'אדני' בשום כתב יד אחר ; ואילו בכל ארבעה-עשר מן המקרים בהם מופיע 'אדני' בנוסח המסורה, אתה מוצא כתבי-יד בודדים בהם הוא מיוצג בשם המפורש . אשר למגילת קומראן ( : QLam, col . III 4 frg . 3 ) , כאן במקרה אחד ( א, יד ) 'אדני' של נוסח המסורה מיוצג בשם המפורש ; ובמקרה אחד ( א, יח ) השם המפורש של נוסח המסורה מיוצג בשם 'אדני' .
>
> השוואת הממצא במגילה לעומת הממצא המקביל במקרא כולו (מחוץ למגילה) מראה כי השם המרובע מופיע במקרא בנפרד כ-6,700 פעמים, בעוד שהשם "אדני" מופיע בנפרד רק כ- 120 פעמים. לרוב (315 פעמים), שם זה מופיע בצירוף השכיח "אדני ה'", שבו 'אדני' הוא לא שם אלוהי, כי אם תואר של כבוד לשמו המפורש של ה', שהוא העיקר. עובדה זו, וכן הממצא האפיגרפי מלפני החורבן (ראו אחיטוב, הכתב והמכתב 2 , עמ' 478), מעידים שבתקופת בית-ראשון השם הפרטי, של אלוהי ישראל, היה אך ורק השם המרובע, ואילו הכינוי 'אדנָי' שימש רק תואר של כבוד שנלווה לעתים לשם המרובע ( לרוב בצירוף "אדני ה" ).

Comment: *Alef dale nun yud* signifies the *middas ha'din* which is appropriate for Eichah?

Comment: I don't think this tracks with the way it's used in comparison to the tetragrammaton in Eicha. I suggest https://mg.alhatorah.org/TanakhLab/Eikhah/1/1/5/22 as an easy way to see the usages more clearly.

Comment: Following the usage of *alef daled nun yed* in Eichah, as per the site you referenced, it seems the beginning of Eichah talks about how the *benei yisrael* were struck by this Name, but in the end were reconciled even with this representation of God - *ki lo yiznach le'olam...*.

Comment: I do not find this compelling either. There are plenty of uses of the tetragrammaton that are for harsh punishment. If you're response is that _even_ the Midas Harachamim was punishing them, I ask then what meaning has been retained and still do not see meaning in the many uses of both names throughout the book using the proposed distinction. See also 2:18-19 which seem to use אדני for a cry for mercy.

Answer (score 2):

This is a great question, as I've rarely seen this discussed in rabbinic literature, and more in academic scholarship. I'll offer an example from both.

The Ḥida, in his commentary *Naḥal Eshkol*, comments, rather obliquely, that the appearance of the name אדני emphasizes Hashem's quality of judgment (*midat hadin*), a kabbalistic concept related to the *sefira* of kingship (*Malchut*). For the passuk 1:15, the Ḥida writes:

> סלה כל אבירי שנפטרו כל הצדיקים אז מוכרח אדני מדת הדין בקרבו ונסתלקו מפני הרעה העתידה
>
> He spurned all my champions--the righteous who died--so it must be אדני (Master) as the quality of judgement in His midst that left for the future evil

The Ḥida similarly writes in the previous passage (1:14) that the name אדני relates to *Malkhut* ("אדני דינא דמלכותא").

For a simpler, academic explanation, see Johan Renkema's chapter "The Literary Structure to Lamentations (I-IV)" in *The Structured Analysis of Biblical and Canaanite Poetry*, who suggests that the names were deliberately chosen per passage, and that it doesn't have to do with pronouncing Hashem's name:

> At first sight the variation between the two divine names seems to be chosen at random. There also exists a considerable variation between the two names in the manuscript traditions. Therefore it is not likely that in the autograph of the booklet only י-ה-ו-ה has been used which, because of fear of pronouncing this divine name, later on was replaced by אדני. (p. 318)

Instead, the changing names offer different meanings. Here is how Gideon Kotzé, in his *The Qumran Manuscripts of Lamentations: A Text-Critical Study*, summarizes Renkema's study of the subject:

> The *Tetragrammaton* is predominantly mentioned in contexts of prayer and utterances of trust. On occasion it is said that י-ה-ו-ה oppresses or executes judgment. Contrastingly, אדני is found in passages with harsh terminology: Adonai hands over (1:14), piles up the strong ones (1:15), treads Daughter Zion as in a winepress (1:15), engulfs with a cloud in his anger (2:1), swallows up without pity (2:2), becomes like an enemy (2:5) and rejects his alter (2:7). This divine name is used considerably fewer times in positive statements (3:31 and 3:58). Renkema concludes from this that God's dominion and might dominate those contexts where אדני appears and, therefore, that this divine name fits the immediate context of the canticle better than י-ה-ו-ה does. (p. 92)

Although the writers of these two types of commentaries couldn't be any further from each other--one an 18th century Sephardi kabbalist, the other a modern academic scholar--they both argue that the name אדני emphasizes the severity of particular punishments.